# Obtaining coverage with Istanbul when stubbing with Sinon

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, istanbul

I have the below function which I stub out using Sinon but am partly unable to get registered as covered when using Istanbul:

```
var funct1 = function(a, b ,c, callback(err, resp) {
    //do something
      someFunction.authenticate(d, e , callback(error, respObj))

});
```

someFunction - an external module in the same project folder
as authenticate - a custom function in someFunction module for which the stub has to be created. It returns a callback with two parameter `err` and `resp` like below

I created a stub in the below fashion,

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var functionSub = sinon.stub(the path to someFunction, "authenticate");

functionStub.returns(function() {
   return (null, {});
}
```

While using Mocha and Istanbul I tested the coverage but I am not able to get it for someFunction.authenticate(d, e , *callback(error, respObj)*) the italic ed line.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, something like below should work for you.

```
const auth = require('path-to-auth');
const sinon = require('sinon);

describe('Auth', () => {
  it('should call authenticate', () => {
    const authMock = sinon.stub(auth, 'authenticate').returns(() => {});
    // call the function to be tested here
    expect(auth.authenticate.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    auth.authenticate.restore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Its throwing an error "AssertionError: expected [Function: proxy] to equal true". For my purpose, I have use the stub in many test cases and have to declare them in a beforeEach loop. Could you tell me the further steps from this.

Comment: check the updated answer.  You can stub it in `it` block or in `beforeEach` it doesn't matter. But be sure to restore it after the use.

Comment: i just tested this and is working, make sure this line is correct in your file -->  `expect(auth.authenticate.calledOnce).to.equal(true);`

Comment: can you update with the code you are trying (in the question) ?